# Picture/Image of a usercontrol

Tags: c#, wpf, image, user-controls

Very simple question. I want to take a picture/image of a usercontrol very often and display that picture somewhere else in my application. I am not going to save the image to the disk.

The question is, how do I take a image of usercontrol?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Easy, use a [VisualBrush](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.visualbrush.aspx). Just point the VisualBrush's Visual property to the control that you want to paint somewhere else. It will update automatically.

Example
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms771563.aspx

Comment: Looks good! Just what I wanted :) However I am a little disappointed it doesnt support Image but only Rectangle and Border from what I understand.

Comment: No, it should support anything that derives from Visual. Do you mean you want to use the visual as a BitmapSource for an Image control? Or do you want to capture an Image control?

Comment: I would like something like: myImage = visualBrush;
Reason is that Image has a stretch property. I want to make sure that the image/visualbrush is uniform.

Comment: Ignore my comment. You can set the streth property on the visualbrush. This works perfectly :) Thanks!